# A) Find Intersection Omega and prove your conjecture. Let Omega ={An: N=1,2,3,...}, where An={0, n, n+1, n+2...}

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let Omega ={An: N=1,2,3,...}, where An={0, n, n+1, n+2...}

A) Find Intersection Omega and prove your conjecture.
B) Find Union Omega and prove your conjecture.

I'm completely lost on these types of questions. I have reached out to our group chat for class and the teacher for help with no responses yet

Comment: $1.$ Use MathJax to write formulas, otherwise it just becomes unsightly and confusing or ambiguous.$$$$
$2.$ Show us your attempts to solve the task so that we can really help you and not just solve the task.

Comment: Hint: Work with cases, and use the definition of intersection and union.

Comment: Ok I was not aware of MathJax and as far as showing the attempts I really dont have much or just dont know exactly where to start. Sean I will go with your advice

Answer (score 1):

The sad thing is I think you don't understand the class material as presented.  There isn't much to these problems *other* than comprehension.

In this $A_1 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,,.....\}$ and $A_2 = \{0, 2,3,4,5,6,7,.......\}$ and $A_3=\{0,3,4,5,6,.....\}$ and so on.... $A_{137} = \{0, 137, 138, 139,....\}$ and $A_{56789}= \{0, 567889, 567890, 567891,....\}$ and $A_k = \{0, k, k+1, k+2, k+3,.....\}$.

$\Omega$ is a collection of all these sets.  The question is asking what is the intersection of all these sets.

The intersection refers to the set you get when you consider all the elements that are contained in each and every set.  So what elements do the sets $ \{0,1,2,3,4,5,,.....\}$ and $ \{0, 2,3,4,5,6,7,.......\}$ and $\{0,3,4,5,6,.....\}$ etc. all have in common?  What is the set that contains all the elements in common?

Hint:  $1$ is not in the intersection as it is not in all the sets; $1$ is not an element of $A_2, A_3$ and so on.  And $2$ is not in the intersection as $2$ is not in $A_3 = \{0,3,4,5,6,....\}$.

....

So this is what the question is asking you to do.

1. Make a conjecture about what you think the intersection is.
2. Prove your conjecture.